No module named 'snowflake' when run the streamlit app in anaconda environment
I have a Streamlit app that connects with Snowflake in my local Anaconda virtual environment. It returns an error message when I run it locally with the command:
streamlit run src/local.py
The error message is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'

I'm running it in an Anaconda environment. Here's my requirements.yaml file:
name: snowpark_local_py11

channels:
  - snowflake
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python==3.11
  - openai
  - langchain
  - langchain-community
  - snowflake-sqlalchemy
  - snowflake-snowpark-python=1.9.0
  - snowflake-connector-python=3.11.0

Interestingly, when I host it on Streamlit or use non-Anaconda environments like pyenv or Streamlit Community, it works fine. The requirements.txt for those environments is
streamlit
openai
langchain
langchain-community
snowflake-sqlalchemy
snowflake-snowpark-python=1.9.0
snowflake-connector-python=3.11.0

Has anyone had a similar issue before?
I have seen this solution: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/snowflake-connector-modulenotfound-only-on-streamlit-app/29038/2
but I don't have any python package called 'snowflake'
